# HTML css image class shows up in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I am generating an html, where I have an image class as shown. I can view the image correctly in chrome/safari. But while the text is shown in Firefox the image does not

By incorrectly I mean that the image does not show

```css
img.wink  {
    content: url(data:image/.gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPALMMAP/qAEVFRQAAAP/OAP/JAP6dAP+0AP/+k//9E///x//lAP//6wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAwALAAAAAAPAA8AAARXkEkZap2Y1ZXOGRcWcAgCnEMRTEEnnDCQrtrxxjCoJSZw+y+CKnDo/WAEQ+WAwyUrvWZQGRg0TwKFcFX1xYI6zWCgEJizhBlrTGi31aKAYW4YZlgW2iQCADs=);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<img class="wink" />
I am not insane
```

edit:

ok so following up on @joshadams response it seems like I have to use a different way to support firefox/chrome. Is there a simple way which would work for both?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Comment: @JoshAdams could you elaborate? What am I supposed to see here? Why is this only a problem in Firefox

Comment: @JoshAdams - I think you posted something and then deleted? :P

Comment: Sorry I was wrong at first but fixed it now :)

Comment: Let me know if that helps @tsar2512

Comment: Glad you got it all sorted out! Sorry I couldn't provide a single solution for you, hope I helped some. Best of luck in your coding @tsar2512 !

Comment: def helped... upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think img is not waiting for a content, but for a src, you can try that trick.

```css
img.wink,
img.wink::after  {
    content: url(data:image/.gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPALMMAP/qAEVFRQAAAP/OAP/JAP6dAP+0AP/+k//9E///x//lAP//6wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAwALAAAAAAPAA8AAARXkEkZap2Y1ZXOGRcWcAgCnEMRTEEnnDCQrtrxxjCoJSZw+y+CKnDo/WAEQ+WAwyUrvWZQGRg0TwKFcFX1xYI6zWCgEJizhBlrTGi31aKAYW4YZlgW2iQCADs=);
}
.wink {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(data:image/.gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPALMMAP/qAEVFRQAAAP/OAP/JAP6dAP+0AP/+k//9E///x//lAP//6wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAwALAAAAAAPAA8AAARXkEkZap2Y1ZXOGRcWcAgCnEMRTEEnnDCQrtrxxjCoJSZw+y+CKnDo/WAEQ+WAwyUrvWZQGRg0TwKFcFX1xYI6zWCgEJizhBlrTGi31aKAYW4YZlgW2iQCADs=) no-repeat left center;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<span class="wink"></span>
<br/>
I am not insane
```

Answer (score 1):

need to add the ::after for firefox or sometimes ::before depending on version: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/

```css
/*firefox*/
img.wink::after  {
    content: url(https://sites.psu.edu/siowfa16/files/2016/10/YeDYzSR-10apkm4.png);
}
/*chrome*/
img.wink  {
    content: url(https://sites.psu.edu/siowfa16/files/2016/10/YeDYzSR-10apkm4.png);
    height:10px;
    width: 10px:
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<img class="wink" />
<br/>
I am not insane <img class="win ab" width = "30px" />
```

Comment: interesting what does `::after` signify? Will this work for all browsers? This is a generated HTML so I can modify my code to generate accordingly

Comment: "::after is a pseudo element which allows you to insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the HTML). While the end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on the page as if it is"

Comment: You could also link to the src directly in your html using a url and you would not need the psedo element.

Comment: uggh.. so now this doesn't show up correctly on chrome... I'll have to have two versions for two different browsers? Is there no way to have the same... I cannot use the src directly in the html. I want to de-duplicate the same image being used to reduce the size of the html.

Comment: Sorry this is the way I know :( you can combine the two into one to make it shorter in css. I usually just use a library/webkit to handle the different browsers for me